# How is one structure mapped to another by something like "return (struct a *) b"

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm trying to understand the linux kernel network code and I come up across many functions like

```
static inline struct tcp_sock *tcp_sk(const struct sock *sk)
{
        return (struct tcp_sock *)sk;
}
```

The contents of the structures `sock` and `tcp_sock` are quite different. How does this mapping exactly happen? Do the structure members with the same name and type get mapped to each other?

**Edit 1:** To be more specific, in the function `tcp_v4_connect`

```
struct tcp_sock *tp = tcp_sk(sk);
tp->write_seq = secure_tcp_sequence_number(inet->inet_saddr,
                           inet->inet_daddr,
                           inet->inet_sport,
                           usin->sin_port);
err = tcp_connect(sk);
```

And then in the function `tcp_connect` called above,

```
struct tcp_sock *tp = tcp_sk(sk);
tcp_init_nondata_skb(buff, tp->write_seq++, TCPHDR_SYN);
```

The variable `write_seq` exists only in the `struct tcp_sock` so how can it's value have been passed on to the function `tcp_connect` when only the `struct sock *sk` was passed to it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the structure members with the same name and type get mapped to each other?

No.

```
struct sock sk; /* our sock struct */
struct tcp_sock *tcp_sk = (struct tcp_sock *)&sk;
```

The `tcp_sk` pointer now simply points to memory pointed to by `&sk`. By accessing `tcp_sk` fields now you will access the memory assigned to this pointer but in order to get expected result the data stored at both addresses should be valid.

Now, `struct sock` (network layer representation of sockets) has s`truct sock_common` as it's first member:

```
306 struct sock {
307         /*
308          * Now struct inet_timewait_sock also uses sock_common, so please just
309          * don't add nothing before this first member (__sk_common) --acme
310          */
311         struct sock_common      __sk_common;
```

And `struct tcp_sock` has `struct inet_connection_sock` as it's first member

```
struct tcp_sock {
138         /* inet_connection_sock has to be the first member of tcp_sock */
139         struct inet_connection_sock     inet_conn;
```

and this struct has `struct inet_sock` as it's first member:

```
 90 struct inet_connection_sock {
 91         /* inet_sock has to be the first member! */
 92         struct inet_sock          icsk_inet;
```

and guess what struct is the first member of `inet_sock`... It is `struct sock`:

```
172 struct inet_sock {
173         /* sk and pinet6 has to be the first two members of inet_sock */
174         struct sock             sk;
```

So by accessing `tcp_sk.inet_conn.icsk_inet.sk` you are accessing our `sock` struct.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question for a more precise doubt. Can you look at that as well?

Comment: sk works as handle in this code, by accessing tp->write_seq you are accessing memory at address of sk offset by write_seq member position and it must be secured that memory can be accessed

Comment: Since the sequence number is such a crucial variable for TCP, how can it be ensured to remain unmodified during multiple function calls (e.g., moving on to TCP send from TCP connect)? I couldn't find anything on reserving the memory in the code.

Comment: It is assured by careful checking of what kind of network connection struct sock represents.

Comment: Ok. I'm trying to do something similar for my protocol. Can you point me to where in the code it's ensured that the memory allocated to the struct tcp_sock is not violated? or can I just implement a similar struct for my protocol and expect it to work like tcp_sock?

Answer (score 3):

As the construct is merely a *cast*, nothing is "mapped", nothing at the memory location that `sk` points to is actually changed.

This only works if the structures are similar or are at least starting with the same fields at the same offsets.

In linux kernel code you can see that `struct sock` and `struct tcp_sock` have all of the fields of `struct sock` in common (`tcp_sock` contains an `inet_connection_sock`which contains an `inet_sock` which in turn contains a `sock` as first elements, respectively). So, "*the contents of the structures...are quite different*", is not quite true. They are actually identical (at least for the size of a `struct sock`).

In order to be able to do this properly, the system somehow "must know" that it can safely cast a `struct sock` to a `struct tcp_sock` - This information is normally hidden somewhere in the common header, in this case in the `struct sock` part (I haven't checked recently, but I guess here the information is in `sk_family`)

After your edit:

What is actually passed to your function is *a pointer to a memory region*. Whatever has there been before is **not changed** by the cast (as I said above). If we can safely assume that `sk` was a pointer to a `struct tcp_sock` some time before, we can safely cast it back to such a beast. This is often done in code that moves around data that has a *generic* and a *specific* part (as in this case). All socket (TCP, UDP, generic, Unix sockets,...) data has common data that is collected in a `struct sock` at the beginning of all specific socket structures. So, on incoming socket data, all of the generic parts of that structures are first handled by functions handling a `struct sock`, later one there must be some big `switch...case` that looks into the specific parts, then passing on a *specific* pointer type.

This allows a `layered`programming approach, where everything is first cast to a generic `struct sock`, then the generic part is handled by functions common for all socket types, later on, the pointer is cast back to what it *originally was*, and the specific part is handled by specialist functions. All the time, the memory area that is basically used as a "backpack" on a `struct sock` to hold specific data is simply left unchanged.

Comment: Thank you, that clears up some of my ignorance. I've just edited the question to add some specific details, can you look into that?